# How to Stop windows stop code with blue screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, windows-8.1

I have problem in my laptop every time i start laptop it shows me blue screen with windows stop code.

also every time i see different windows stop code error.

in starting i have windows 8 os in my laptop but due to this stop code error i upgraded to windows 10 but then also it shows me stop code error.

is anything wrong with my laptop hardware?

How to stop that blue screen stopcode error?

Comment: Will it eventually start or does it never start?  If it starts, look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Reliability History. What errors do you see. Update BIOS, Chipset, Video, Network and all other drivers.  Restart and see if the stop code goes away. Restart and press F8 repeatedly to get into Safe Mode and see if that works.

Comment: Please update question w/ error codes displayed on the BSOD. I personally would recommend backing up your user data in  `%UserProfile%` via: `DISM /Capture-Image /ImageFile:"Z:\UserData.wim" /CaptureDir:"C:\Users\<username>" /Name:"User Data Backup" /Description:"2019.12.05: Backup of %UserProfile%" /Compress:max /CheckIntegrity /Verify`, run [Belarc Advisor](https://www.belarc.com/products_belarc_advisor), copy the HTML report to external media & clean install Win10. Since you experienced this before & after the upgrade, a clean install is likely the most efficient way to resolve the issue.